# GCC Headers - what do they resolve to?

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I find GCC header files to be almost impossible to read.
For example in `ctypes.h` every type or macro is defined via another type or macro.
Is there some way I can get a piece of text that  will tell me what for example
the following eventually becomes? (I don't care about this in particular; it is just an example.)

```
#  define isxdigit_l(c,l)   __isxdigit_l ((c), (l))
```

I could try compiling a file of includes with `gcc -E` but I don't think that will tell me what I want to know.

Comment: `gcc -E` will show you the output of the preprocessor, with all macros expanded.  If that isn't what you want, then what *do* you want?

Comment: I'm probably missing something. but here is a typical result from a file created with the -E switch:extern long int syscall (long int __sysno, ...) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2)));
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__const__)); Frankly that does not help my understanding much. Another example is the typedef for say fpos_t;

Comment: If you want to see what `isxdigit_l` expands to, you need to place an instance of it in your code.  Then `gcc -E` will see that instance and expand it, and you can look at the result.  If you don't reference it, then there won't be anything to expand and you won't see anything.

Comment: Those attributes all look like compiler hints that are probably specific to `gcc`.  You can read about them [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: OK I will try that. One reason for this Q is that often I call a function that I read in some doc, and gcc gives me a bunch of type errors. Then I have to go thru /usr/include looking for the correct .h file to add to my pgm.

Comment: The best way to see how to properly call a function is to look at the documentation in the man page for the function.  That should tell you both (1) what header files(s) you need to include, and (2) what the argument and return types are.  You shouldn't need to dig into the implementation to see how to call it.

Comment: "Then I have to go thru /usr/include looking for the correct .h file" This is most definitely not a good idea. Code to the specification, not to an implementation.

Comment: @TomKarzes I mostly agree with the sense of your comment, but I just have to point out that "You shouldn't need to" is often a real insult on SO and other forums.  If someone didn't need to, they wouldn't have asked.  In this case, what if the documentation is missing or inadequate?  We used to tell novices to [UTS,L](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UTSL.html), and pitied those who couldn't.  But now, we're telling them they shouldn't even try.  Times change.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well sure, if the man page is broken then all bets are off.  But the man pages shouldn't be so broken that they don't even show how to call the function.  There's nothing wrong with looking at the source, for any of a number of reasons, but if it's necessary to do so just to see how to call a function, then something is seriously wrong with the documentation for that function.

Comment: @TomKarzes As the OP said, `isxdigit` was only an example.  The basic calling structure, of a standard function, whose name you know, that you'll certainly be able to find in the official documentation.  But there are all sorts of other questions that come up, all the time, involving non- or semi-standard functions, or functions you don't know the names of yet, or nuances beyond the number and types of a function's arguments.  For the hardest questions you may have to go to the actual source, but for many questions, looking at a `.h` file *used* to be an excellent, intermediate investigation.

Comment: Here's an example: "What are all the values that `errno` can take on?"  Once upon a time, all you had to do was look at `/usr/include/errno.h`.  They were all right there.  Today, I defy you to at all easily find the answer -- me, after about the seventh nested header file, I invariably give up.

Comment: @SteveSummit I dunno, `man errno` usually does this for me.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That's a fair point.  (And I have to say I love your new username.)  Although -- and I don't want to seem argumentative -- I'll bet you $20 that on any system where we tried it, `man errno` would give a different list than implied by `#include <errno.h>` on that same system.  Also on the first system where I tried it, `man errno` gave me "No manual entry for errno".  (Although, on the second system where I tried it, `man errno` not only worked, it told me about `errno(1)`, a command to list current errno values.  Which when I tried it gave me "command not found".)

Comment: Thanks much for all the hard won wisdom; just for 'fun' I did do a `man errno` and got a man page that told me that all the possible values of errno could be found in /usr/include/errno.h but they are not there. Instead there are other files included and macros defined. there are also 8 errno.h files in the /usr/include tree. Of course `errno -l` did not work either as the error cmd is not installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the answer is "no".  What you're seeing is, sadly, the state of the art in modern C compilers and libraries.  It's not just gcc -- every compiler I use these days has the same problem.

Once upon a time, peeking at a standard header file was a great way of learning about the functions it declared.  Today, it's just not, and if you can't find the answer to your question by reading the official documentation, you may be out of luck.

Why is it this way?  Why are the headers so complicated?  I believe it's because C is now a mature language, and the people who write the standard libraries have now had almost 50 years to keep making them "better and better".  But the definition of "better" is "higher performance", or "simultaneously applicable to a wider variety of operating systems and processor architectures".  But it's pretty clear that "readability by end users" has ceased to be any kind of a requirement.

Comment: "the people who write the standard libraries have now had almost 50 years to keep making them "better and better"" . . . I've had "I'm getting old" moments in conversation and physical effort, but that's the first sentence I've read that got me.

Comment: @jthill I had to double-check my math when I wrote that!  Me, I've been using C since 1980, but it doesn't seem like *that* long...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way I can get a piece of text that will tell me what for example the following eventually becomes?

Yes - use an IDE or tool that does that. For example in [eclipse](https://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/macro-expansions/) just put your mouse  over it...

([image]

Comment: That sounds like a useful idea. But if eclipse can do it, there should be a utility that can do it, or at least an algorithm.

Comment: Of course it would help if eclipse would actually run. It looks correctly installed in synaptic, but when i go to launch it i get a message to look at a log file. The logfile contains: !SESSION Thu Jun 24 23:09:44 PDT 2021 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2021-06-24 23:09:44.197
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) <SNIP>

Comment: `But if eclipse can do it, there should be a utility` utility recommendations are offtopic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You choose your example well:

- defined as **function and macro**
- is part of a group
- has a locale version

The line you show is inside a `# ifndef __NO_CTYPE`. If it *is* defined (e.g. by compiling with `-D__NO_CTYPE`) then you get a function call in the binary.

The extern function declaration is indirect:

`__exctype_l (isxdigit_l);`

But everything is together and commented.

---

Actually before you "dig" into the H-files (and wonder what they mean) you should by aware that this prototype:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int isxdigit(int c);
```

**can also be a macro.**

To get the official function as a function (and not just the functionality) you can also undef it:

```
...
#undef isxdigit_l
int is = isxdigit_l('f', loc);
...
```

This *eventually becomes*:

```
0000000000001050 <isxdigit_l@plt>:
    1050:       ff 25 d2 2f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fd2]        # 4028 <isxdigit_l@GLIBC_2.3>
```

Otherwise (normal case, your line) there is no trace of the isxdigit_l "function" call.